# Why is the image of the map $f(x) =(sin(x),1- cos(x))$ for $x\in [0, 2\pi)$ and $f =\operatorname{id}$ otherwise not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the map $f: (-\infty, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t $f(x) = (sin(x), 1- cos(x))$ for $x\in [0, 2\pi)$ and $f(x) = (\operatorname{id}(x), 0)$ for the rest of its domain.

In the book of Chillingworth, *Differential Topology*, it is stated that the image of this map is not a sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ even though it has maximal rank for any point on its domain.

However, I cannot understand why it is the case, i.e why the image is not a sub manifold ?

[image]

Comment: And what is $\iota$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the identity map

Comment: And so $f(-1)=-1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is basically the map that rounds the positive part of $\mathbb{R}$ (or rather the positive part of the given domain) around the circle, but it does not cross itself; it is like a snail.

Comment: But $-1\notin\mathbb R^2$. Therefore, your map $f$ is **not** a map from $(-\infty,2\pi)$ into $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right; I formulated wrong, please see my edit.

Comment: The function $f$ isn't even continuous at $0$. Therefore, it makes to sense to say that it has maximal rank at that point.

Comment: How about quoting exactly what Chilingworth says, instead of your own paraphrase?

Comment: @GEdgar it does not give an explicit map; it just show the image.

Comment: Can you give us the image?

Comment: @PaulFrost See my edit please.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Seeing the image I guess the problem is that the topologies from R and the relative to R2 are not compatible. The open of R that maps into the straight line is not the intersection of the image with any open of R2

Comment: @AlejandroMenaya You are right; if it is not topologically a subspace, it cannot be a sub manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a submanifold because the region near $(0,0)$ is not locally hoeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Take any neighborhood of $(0,0)$, remove $(0,0)$ from it, and you will get at least three connected components. If it was locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, then you should get only two connected components in some cases.

Comment: where did that third component come from ? I cannot see it.

Comment: Look again at the picture that you have posted. Near $(0,0)$, it looks like a rotated Y letter.

Comment: yes, but the tail and the right arm of that "y" are connected by the part of circle which does not contain the origin.

Comment: Please read again what I wrote. I wrote about a **neighborhood** of $(0,0)$, not about the whole space.

Comment: You are right.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A circle together with a half-line going to the left.

The point at the bottom of the circle is your problem, where no neighborhood of it is homeomorphic to $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Comment: See my edit please; that is not the image that we are looking for :)

Comment: OK, changed....